# Direct User to URL when Back Button is Clicked

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

I am using a mobile webview in my android app and am hoping to make it so that when the user clicks the back button, they are automatically taken back to the home screen.

I understand that I can use the onbeforeunload method to perform a function when the user clicks back.

The code below doesn't seem to be working properly:

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    window.location("http://www.google.com");
}
</script>
```

Strangely, if I replace `window.location(http://www.google.com");` with `alert("You clicked back");` then it works just fine.

Does anyone know why this isn't working right? Is the browser preventing me from directing the user to another URL?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `location.href="http://www.google.com";`.

Depending on your application though, you're probably better off using [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to change the current app's state and do something on the popState event.